# Two Sets such that their Union and Intersection are Connected but One of the Sets is not

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can anyone think of two sets such that their intersection and union are connected, but one of the sets is not connected. I know one of the sets must be open, but I can't think of an example.

Comment: What do you mean you "know one of the sets must be open"? Is that a requirement of the problem, or did you deduce that somehow?

Comment: $A = D \cup \{(2,0)\}$, $B = \mathbb{R}^2 - \{(2,0)\}$, where $D$ is the open unit disk about $(0,0)$. And it doesn't have to be that one is open.

Comment: $A = [0,1] \cup \bigl([1,2] \cap \mathbb{Q}\bigr)$ and $B = [0,1] \cup \bigl([1,2] \cap \mathbb I\bigr)$ where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the rationals and $\mathbb{I}=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ is the irrationals. Note, neither $A$ nor $B$ is open.

Comment: @LeeMosher closure is a requirement for this proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495338/if-union-and-intersection-of-two-subsets-are-connected-are-the-subsets-connecte

Comment: @Cococabana So for your question to be possible one of the sets must *not be closed*. Open is not the same as not closed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest example I can think of is taking $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus A$. Now $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ are both connected, but $B$ is not connected. In fact, choosing $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ gives two disconnected sets, whose union and intersection are both connected.

If you do not consider the empty set connected (certain authors don't), then you can take $A=\{0,1\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $B=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{1\}$.  Now $B$ is connected and $A$ is not, while $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A\cap B=\{0\}$ are both connected.

Answer (score 1):

Try always to vizualize in Real Line. 
Consider A=(-3,5) and B=(-4,-3]U(-1,2).
Now check that A union B is connected and A intersection B is connected.
But, B is disconnected.

Comment: With $A=(0,1)\cup (2,4)$ and $B=[1,3)\cup [4,5)$, we even have that *both* sets $A$ and $B$ are disconnected

Comment: @Hagen .Yaa you can now make numerous such examples. Mine was just a hint to Cococabana's question.