# If union and intersection of two subsets are connected, the subsets are connected

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

I've been able to prove what is proved here [If union and intersection of two subsets are connected, are the subsets connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495338/if-union-and-intersection-of-two-subsets-are-connected-are-the-subsets-connecte)

However, I was wondering if I could get some help finding an example to show that $A$ and $B$ must be closed.

Comment: $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{I} \cup \{0\}$ are not closed. $A \cap B = \{0\}$ and $A \cup B = \mathbb{R}$, yet neither $A$ nor $B$ is connected.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $A=[0,1] \cup (2,3)$, and $B=[1,2]$ as a counterexample.

Comment: A counterexample was already given with a singleton intersection in the comments.