# Given union and intersection of two open sets connected, does this imply both sets are connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$, $B$ be a nonempty subsets of $X$. Given their union and intersection connected. If $A$ and $B$ are open sets, then is it true that both $A$ and $B$ are connected? I know if both are closed then both are connected. I am not able to construct a counterexample for open case. Is it true too?

Comment: Yes and the proof is essentially the same too.

Comment: A small proviso: the intersection is non-empty.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495338/if-union-and-intersection-of-two-subsets-are-connected-are-the-subsets-connecte?noredirect=1&lq=1

I just added a comment onto the answer... but is exactly the same.